# labeling and saving transparent layer in photoshop

Tags: photoshop, transparent

I am a newbie to photoshop. I have some images that I need to label by hand to feed to a machine learning algorithm for classification. 
The labeling accepted by the code bundle I will be running on is supposed to depict the features I am interested in, and the other unlabeled pixels are to be black.
For instance, I have a picture of land, and I will have to paint on it with red to mark the rocks, and blue to mark the soil. The other regions in the picture will be black. SO my labeling image should have red (rock) and blue (soil) and black (unclassified).
I am told I need to do this with transparent layer on top of my actual picture, and I can paint on the transparent layer as I want, and save that transparent layer as my label image. 
My questions are:

1. How do I draw on the transparent layer (I am reducing the opacity to
   0 because I want a transparent layer, right?)
2. How do I paint the unlabeled pixels black? (because that is what the program recognizes
   as unclassified)
3. How do I save the transparent layer as a 8-bit image?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be related to programming as stated in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Anything you draw on a layer with zero opacity will not show! You need an *empty* layer, not a zero opacity layer. To make this, ensure your Layers palette is visible by pressing `F7`. Then, at the bottom right corner of the Layers palette, beside the trashcan, select `New layer`.

2) To paint pixels black, press `d` for *default colours* since black is the default colour. Then press `B` for `Brush`. Now you can paint on the empty layer. Press `[` to make the brush smaller and `]` to make it bigger. Click the black foreground colour square on top of the square white background colour in the Tool palette (left side of my picture) to change colours.

3) To save the classification layer only, click on the *eye* icon in the Layers palette of the other layers that you don't want in order to turn them off. That way only the layer you want will be saved. Then click `File->Save for Web` and select a file format that supports transparency - i.e. `PNG` or `GIF`, but NOT `JPEG` or `TIF`.

I have marked in green, all the buttons I mention that you will need to click on.

[image]